# Custom Data Responses

Tags: custom-fields

How can I view responses to custom data questions? By looking at Contact summary I can see that new contacts are responding, but when I click on the link, nothing is there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE (where other users of civicrm try to voluntarily help other users). I think you will need to expand your Question to explain more clearly as currently I don't understand what you mean by 'custom data questions'. Do you mean Profiles? And what do you mean by 'click on the link'. thx

Comment: When individuals complete the "membership application" form to first become a member or renew membership, they respond to the "custom question:"Would you like to join a section or committee?"  They are given a drop down list from which to choose a response.

Comment: If that field is set to 'searchable' then you should be able to find it in Adv Search or Search Builder and therefore search for who set it to which option. If the field isn't showing in Adv Search then you need to find it in Admin > Customise > Custom fields, and set it to Searchable. not sure if that helps as I still don't quite grasp the issue you are having.

Comment: And I still don't understand what you mean by 'when i click on the link'. what link, where?

Comment: That is helpful; however I am still unable to search for the question. I have located it using the method you explained. Each time I attempt to edit the "no" to the "yes" for "searchable,' it switches back to "no." It won't allow me to edit.

Comment: I just got it to save the Custom Data question. Many thanks. Now I'm trying to figure out how to search for contacts who have responded to the question. Any suggestions? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: And, I just found my list. Yay! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Each custom field is part of a group, that is itself attached to a "normal" civicrm entity (that can be a contact, an activity, a participant...), so the first thing you need to do is to find to what the custom group is attached.

the second thing it to be sure it's searchable. You can find both of them in the admin custom fields.

once you know where it is and that it's searchable, you can use the advance search, and you will have that field

As a side note: if your question provides a list of groups (all the sections or committees) it's probably going to be easier for you to ignore the custom field and directly show the list of groups